# How to change date format of date input in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I created this code sample for get the date from a date picker. I need to push the date value into the paragraph element as default (YYYY-MM-DD) but I need the date input to show the date as Month-dd-YY (ex: Oct-25-18)

```
<input type="date" id="date" /> <br/>
<button id="btn" onclick="show()">Ok</button><br/>
<p id="p"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function show(){
        var x = document.getElementById('date');
        x.innerHTML = x.value;
        document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = x.value;
    }
</script>
```

I tried with `x.innerHTML = x.value` but not working.

How I can do this?

Comment: `<input type="date">` display value depends on user locale: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing to milliseconds then to JavaScript date. Something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('date');
var msec = Date.parse(x);
var d = new Date(msec);
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = d;
```

Near the bottom of this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code mentioned below. If having a hard time understanding it. Ping me :)

```
<input type="date" id="date" /> <br/>
<button id="btn" onclick="show()">Ok</button><br/>
<p id="p"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

function show(){
    var x = document.getElementById('date');
    var temp_date = new Date(x.value);
    var date = temp_date.getDate();
    var month = temp_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = temp_date.getFullYear();
    format_date = month + " " + date + " " + year;
    x.innerHTML = x.value; // - not sure what you were trying
    // to achieve but x here is input not other element.
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = format_date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using CSS and js with using HTML 5 basic date type input

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="MMM-DD-YY" value="2020-08-29">
```